# Prevent parent window refresh during window.open() IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I want to submit the form data into the pop up window.

```
function doPopUp(link) {

    var goAction = link;
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.target = "newWin";
    form.action = link;
    var scrWidth = screen.availWidth - 20;
    var scrHeight = screen.availHeight - 70;

    var myWindow = window.open("", "newWin", "width="+scrWidth+", height="+scrHeight+", scrollbars=1, toolbar=0, menubar=0");
    myWindow.location = goAction;
    // if (window.focus) {
    //  myWindow.focus();
    // }
    form.submit();       // My guess is this line

}
```

When I use `doPopUp(link)` in the HTML button, I am successfully submit the form data into the new window and the parent window does not direct to the action url. This happen when I use Chrome and Mozilla.

But when I use IE8, the parent window also refreshed. I'm not sure how to tweak my code, as far as I understand, it has something to do the line `form.submit()`.

How can prevent the parent window directed to the action url?

Comment: I dont understand logic of using form here... cant you just user querstring to pass further info , and yes because you obviously submit the form it will post to new location you are changing in form action

Comment: But why chrome and mozilla parent window changing url? Without using the `form.submit()`, the form is not submitted into the target window. Adding all the form value into url parameter is one of the method, but I hoping for answer that can fix this.

Comment: possible reason might be you are changing focus to new window and may be that supportedi n ff and chrome but IE8 , just check in ff / chrome console to see if you get error like form is undefined or not ?

Comment: No error for all 3 browsers, only IE8 behaved differently...

Comment: can you try with removing that focus condition